# Two opposing categorical variables and moving from univariate to multivariate linear regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, linear

My knowledge of statistics is described as "working" or more accurately a very immature "work in progress" so please excuse me if this question is extremely simple.

I am currently writing my masters thesis and as part of my thesis I was provided with output from univariate and multivariate regressions investigating the relationship between 1 dependent variable (A measure of someone's attitude) and approximately 15 independent variables, many of which are categorical with some being continuous.

Two of these independent variables ask effectively opposing questions
Var_1: "Does your practice provide any monitoring services?"
Var_2: "Does your practice provide monitoring service X?" - Where service X is in most cases the bare minimum service provided, and it would be expected that those who respond *no* to the first  question will respond *yes* to the first question. Summary statistics describing the responses to these two questions more or less confirms this.

I have very limited formal knowledge of statistics however what I have observed in the univariate analysis is that both have p values below 0.025 but skyrocket to well over 0.3 and 0.6 in multivariate regression.

Would I be correct in saying that as the two variables are obviously antagonistic and dependent on one another, this explains why they lose statistical significance in the multivariate analysis?

Comment: I believe the term I am looking for with regard to my predictor variables is that they are colinear!

Comment: refer to linear regression assumptions - http://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-linear-regression/ Also while using categorical variables you might want to take look at this as well  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter3/statareg3.htm